# Prove that $ (\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2})^{n}+(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2})^{n-1} = (\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2})^{n+1}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, exponentiation, golden-ratio, geometric-progressions

I have to get from $ (\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2})^{n}+(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2})^{n-1}$ to $(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2})^{n+1}$ however I do not know how to get there since i do not know what to do with the exponents.

(not sure if I used the right tag)

Comment: Hint:  first divide through by $\left( \frac {1+\sqrt 5}2\right)^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Let $\varphi=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt5\right)$; you have to show that $\varphi^n+\varphi^{n-1}=\varphi^{n+1}$. Divide through by $\varphi^{n-1}$ to see that all you really need to show is that $\varphi+1=\varphi^2$. That’s a matter of fairly straightforward arithmetic.

Comment: That does make it a lot easier, thanks.

Comment: And when you write this, **begin** with the proof that $\varphi+1=\varphi^2$, and then multiply by $\varphi^{n-1}$.  Brian tells you how to **find** the proof, but I tell you how to write it in the end.

Comment: @R.vW: You’re welcome. And note **GEdgar**’s comment just above this one: what he says is entirely correct.

Comment: Why is the order important?

Comment: @R.vW: Because you want to the order in which it’s written to follow the order of the logic. You start by showing that $\varphi+1=\varphi^2$. Then from this now known fact you deduce the desired result. If you organize the argument in the opposite order, you’re showing that the desired result implies a true statement (namely, that $\varphi+1=\varphi^2$), but that doesn’t guarantee that the desired result is true. Example: $1=-1$ implies that $1^2=(-1)^2$, which is true, but $1=-1$ is *not* true. The problem here is that the squaring step is not reversible: $a^2=b^2$ does not imply that ...

Comment: ... $a=b$. In your argument all of the steps actually are reversible, but the easiest way to show that is to organize the argument in the right direction in the first place, from true statement to desired conclusion.

Comment: Aah that makes sense, thanks

Comment: @R.vW: My pleasure.